# Can a cleric "multi class" between domains?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric

I have a player asking me if there is a mechanic that would allow them to take on a second domain, much in the same way a player can multi class. My gut here is no and I am contemplating instead finding out which 2 domains they wish to combine and then forming my own homebrew deity and domain that takes aspects of each, but not everything. But is there a RAW way that a player could take on multiple domains as a cleric?

Comment: This sounds like powergaming. Which is fine if your table is into that. But if you’re not, this is probably powergaming.

Comment: He is referencing a mechanic in an old version of DnD that allowed clerics to multi domain. He usually plays life domain for the spell list but wants to try the order domain abilities.